# how to find if unregister_chrdev() call was successful

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

unregister_chrdev() call from [linux\fs.h] used to return 0 if successful and <0 other wise. But now, in newer kernel versions, the return value of the function has been changed to void so it no longer returns any thing.

Question: Is there any way to find out if the unregister_chrdev() call was successful or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The return of void was done by changeset: e53252d97e670a38b1d2e9723b48077bba11ddda

```
commit e53252d97e670a38b1d2e9723b48077bba11ddda
Author: Akinobu Mita 
Date:   Thu Jul 19 01:47:51 2007 -0700

    unregister_chrdev() return void

    unregister_chrdev() does not return meaningful value.  This patch makes it
    return void like most unregister_* functions.
```

In fact if you look at the code before (from 2.6.12-rc2 onwards) you can see it always returned 0 so this is a function that is always expected to succeed.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Linux Kernel Module programming. I googled before posting the question but never thought of looking at the code.

Comment: Getting familiar with the git tools for exploring the code base is a very worthwhile investment. Good luck :-)