# Error compiling kernel module for simple device driver

Tags: c, device-driver, kernel-module

I've got such a function:

```
void cleanup_module(void)
{
    /* 
     * Unregister the device 
     */
    if(unregister_chrdev(Major, DEVICE_NAME)<0) 
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error in unregister_chrdev:\n");
}
```

and error:

```
/home/student/kernel/hello.c: In function ‘cleanup_module’:
/home/student/kernel/hello.c:39:2: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

This line is the one with if statement. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that `unregister_chrdev` doesn't have a return value (it's `void`), but you have put it in an if. That is, you are using a void value which should have been ignored. Hence the error message.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237384/how-to-find-if-unregister-chrdev-call-was-successful) which asks why the return value was changed to void.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0706.3/2231.html) `unregister_chrdev()` used to return an `int` but its return type was changed to `void` as the returned value was meaningless. Remove the `if` entirely from the posted code:

```
unregister_chrdev(Major, DEVICE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the `unregister_chrdev()` function is a `void` type function, i.e. it returns nothing. However, you are checking its return value with the `<` operator.