# How to remove dynamically assigned major number from /proc/devices?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In my kernel driver project I register with a dynamic major number by calling

```
    register_chrdev(0, "xxxxx", &xxxxx);
```

and unregistered my module with

```
    unregister_chrdev(0. "xxxxx");
```

When I load my driver with `insmod`, I received dynamic major number, for example 243, and, after `rmmod`, success removing module.

But, after removing the module `/proc/devices` still shows the major number (243).

How do I get removing my driver to also remove its major number from the list in `/proc/devices`?

Comment: This is a ***programming*** site, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it doesn't appear to be about programming, try Super User. ***Please Note: Without further information of what you're trying to do, this question will not be accepted on Super User.*** As it currently stands **on any Stack Exchange site**, it is unclear what this question is asking.

Comment: @cybermonkey - untrue, this is a programming question involving the authoring of a custom kernel module, specifically why the unregister function call in its removal method is not cleaning up (and by extension, if it should be expected to or what other function call is needed).  The "unclarity" comes from your lack of familiarity with kernel programming.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This question yet still doesn't explain itself, and shows no research effort either.

Comment: Untrue again - the poster has researched the function call necessary to create a device, and is having difficulty with the reverse operation - having written and tested code is exactly what is encouraged.  What is clear is that *you* are not the target audience, but you are not the totality of site membership either  You would probably be happier confining your attention to topics within your familiarity, and leave the others to those who know something about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call register_chrdev() with 0 as the first argument to request the assignment of a dynamic major number, the return value will be the assigned major number, which you should save.

Then when you call unregister_chrdev() **you should pass the saved major number as an argument**, rather than the 0 you were.  Also make sure that the device name argument matches.  And be aware that this function returns a result, which you can check for status/failure - in the latter case you definitely want to printk() a message so that you know that your code has *not* accomplished its goal.

You can see a complete example at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html with the key parts being:

```
static int Major;       /* Major number assigned to our device driver */

int init_module(void)
{
        Major = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);

    if (Major < 0) {
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Registering char device failed with %d\n", Major);
      return Major;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    int ret = unregister_chrdev(Major, DEVICE_NAME);
    if (ret < 0)
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Error in unregister_chrdev: %d\n", ret);
}
```

Also be aware that this method of registering a device is considered outdated - you might want to research the newer method.

Comment: It is not the case that all implementations of unregister_chrdev return an int. See this SO question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237384/how-to-find-if-unregister-chrdev-call-was-successful] Linux 2.6.12 is when the function started returning void. Previously it always returned 0 so nothing was lost by changing its return type. Also I don't blame anyone for following TLDP. I did notice that it only covers kernel versions 2.4.x and 2.6.x.